# Tracking multiple tags or categories

Tags: categories, tags, google-analytics

I'm trying to find a way to track the popularity of multiple categories, tags or custom taxonomies.
On our site we often use multiple categories for a single article - e.g. an article would be classified under "graphic design" and "illustration". Another article might be tagged with only "illustration".
All the methods I've seen to track the popularity of different categories don't take multiple categories into regard. I can't do this using Custom Variables in Google Analytics, nor can I seem to find a sufficient solution with Event Tracking. Custom Variables only allow for one key value and using event tracking would mess up my bounce rate data (each pageload would trigger an event).

The plugins available are also not very accurate - they rate popularity on the amount of articles inside each category, not as views of those articles (over the past month for e.g.).

Is there a method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow different approaches, I will show you a simple one, that hooks into wp_footer action. The lack of this approach is that it slows down the page loading.
To avoid this lack you can use the same logic but implemented via ajax.

So, you can use an option to store category popularity, it will be stored as array where keys are category ids and values are numeric values: bigger this value, bigger popularity.

Please note that all following code is **not** tested.

First of all use wp_footer to 'launch' the count

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'count_category_popularity');
```

and related function:

```
function count_category_popularity() {
  if ( is_single() ) {
    global $post;
    update_category_popularity( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' ) );
  } elseif ( is_category() )  {
    // 3 is the multiplier
    update_category_popularity( get_queried_object(), 3 );
  }
}
```

As you can see, the function above call another function `update_category_popularity` passing all the categories of a single post or the category itself if in the taxonomy archive. In this case second param is passed to function, it is a "multiplier" because I think that if an user require a category archive this must contribute more to the category popularity than viewing an article in that category. This is my opinion, you can delete that param if you want.

Now, the `update_category_popularity` function will be something like this:

```
function update_category_popularity ( $cat = NULL, $count = 1 ) {
  if ( empty($cat) )  return;
  $old = get_option('cat_popularity');
  if ( empty ($old) ) $old = array();
  $new = $old;
  if ( is_array($cat) && ! empty($cat) ) {
    foreach( $cat as $term ) {
    $new[$term->term_id] = ( isset($old[$term->term_id]) ) ? (int)$old[$term->term_id] + $count : $count;
    }
 } elseif( is_object ($cat) )  {
    $new[$cat->term_id] = ( isset($old[$cat->term_id]) ) ? (int)$old[$cat->term_id]+$count : $count;
 }
 if ( $old != $new ) update_option('cat_popularity', $new);
}
```

The function sets the option 'cat_popularity' and you can use it to handle category popularity.

Do you want to know a category popularity? Do:

```
$pop = get_option('cat_popularity');
$cat_popularity = $pop[$cat_id];
```

Do you want all categories ordered by popularity? Do:

```
$pop = get_option('cat_popularity');
// this will sort in reverse order (high to low), for low to high ordering use asort()
arsort($pop);
foreach ( $pop as $cat_id => $popularity ) {
  echo '<li>Category ' . $cat_id . ' popularity is' . $popularity . '</li>';
}
```

Probably is useful for you having a function that return popularity in percentual values instead of absolute ones: if you retrieve that a category popularity is 125, this value stands for high or low popularity?

Using function below you will retrieve popularity of categories in percentual values, help you easy understanding how a category is more or less popular compared with the others, even if you have a single value:

```
function get_categories_perc_popularity() {
   $pop = get_option('cat_popularity');
   arsort($pop);
   $total = array_sum( arry_map('intval', $pop) );
   $out = array();
   foreach ( $pop as $catid => $popularity ) {
     $out[$catid] = ( 100 * $popularity ) / $total;
   }
   return $out;
}
```

Now you can use:

```
$pop = (array) get_categories_perc_popularity();
if ( ! isset($pop[32]) ) $pop[32] = '0';
echo 'Category 32 popularity is ' . $pop[32] . '%';
```

Comment: I noticed now that you want to track different taxonomies and not only categories, the logic is the same, you have to make only small changes in order to make my code work with different taxonomies.